# When converting PDF to Excel with Omnipage or Abbyy Finereader, is there are way to stop it from splitting individual cells?

Tags: excel, pdf, ocr, pdf-conversion, abbyy

I'm trying to extract some tables from PDF files, and both tools (Abbyy and Omnipage) do a pretty good job of identifying the tables. But when it comes to identifying the rows and columns, they both make the same mistakes.

Usually, the problem comes when they create a partial row, splitting just one cell horizontally, but not the others. For an example of what I mean, see the attached image. In the column on the left, some of the cells are split in half, which makes the table difficult to work with in Excel.

I find it odd that these programs do this in the first place, since tables with split cells are always a pain.

Is there a way of telling these programs to set only full columns and rows, and not split individual cells?

Any suggestions for other solutions?

[image]

Comment: are you trying to automate the OCR from your application or looking for end-user application? If the latter then you should better as on Stackexchange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ABBYY has a lot of OCR products, the configurable ones are called FineReader Engine and FlexiLayout Studio. Other ABBYY products does not have the requested settings.

Comment: Thanks. Very helpful. I was not aware of those products.